# WhatsApp not available on Android Sharing Intent

Tags: android, whatsapp, sharing, file-sharing, android-sharing

I was trying to have a Share Button on my Android activity which on clicking should share a '.doc' via available sharing apps. But WhatsApp is not coming in the sharing app chooser.(Gmail/Skype/IMO/AndroidBeam/Save to Google Drive options are available) My  code snippet is given below:

```
public void shareFile() throws MalformedURLException
{
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileToBeSend);
    ArrayList<Uri> fileUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    fileUris.add(fileUri);

    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    sharingIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUris);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Comment: Presumably, WhatsApp does not support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. Only a subset of apps that support `ACTION_SEND` will also support `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. Since you only have one `Uri` in your `ArrayList`, perhaps you might consider using `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare you are right... When I changed it to ACTION_SEND WhatsApp also started coming in the app chooser. Thank you

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried both but still its not showing whtsapp. can you tell what is the issue?